# Technique to truncate vbscript variables

Tags: variables, vbscript, truncate

I need to take zip codes of various lengths from an existing variable and truncate them, when appropriate, to 5 characters.

Will this code work? If not, how can I accomplish this?

```
StateZip = split(splitAddr(1), " ")
StateZip = left(StateZip, 5)
```

Comment: By [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk3xcs8k(VS.85).aspx) `StateZip = left(StateZip, 5)` should work. did you try running it?

Answer (score 1):

```
splitAddr = "123456 12345 1234"
StateZip = split(splitAddr," ") 
For i = LBound(StateZip) To UBound(StateZip)
    StateZip(i) = left(StateZip(i), 5) 
    WScript.Echo StateZip(i)
Next
```